# Broken apport return [Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)]

Tags: apt, package

When I try to update the system or install updates through:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade -y;
```

I get an error:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
When processing the following packages, errors occurred:
 apport
```

I suppressed this error by freezing the package via aptitude, but can we somehow really solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem when I found the broken "deb" package in "/var/cache/apt/archives" and deleted it.